# Denied the registry key permission on windows server 2019

Tags: asp.net

We deployed asp.net web application on windows server 2019,and save database name in registry key, but its shows Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\DATABASE_NAME' is denied.
i have checked permission possibility it has already full access to the user.

[image]

We need experts help to solve this problem

Comment: Your web app on IIS runs under a different account if you didn’t notice yet, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: `save database name in registry key` why? That's not a great idea. `full access to the user.` that's a *very* bad idea. IIS app pool accounts are restricted by design, to limit the damage they can do if a web app gets hacked. Why not save the database or connection string in `web.config`? You can [encrypt sections of `web.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/zhhddkxy(v=vs.100)) to protect them